# Can't get any data back using JSONP when making a cross-domain request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, same-origin-policy

I have a website that I need to send a GET request to from my browser and get HTML data back. But the website has a "X-Frame-Option: DENY" and I can't make an Ajax request because of CORS policy. So I tried it with JSONP but it's not returning me any data. It does says 200 OK for connection though. I'm using the latest version of Chrome.

```
// Not returning HTML back
$.getJSON("https://www.google.com/?callback=?", function(result) {
   console.log(result)
})

// I tried this but also didn't work
$.ajax({
     url: 'https://www.google.com',
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success: function(result) {
         console.log(result)
     }
})
```

I'm not sure what is going on here..

Comment: `X-Frame-Option` isn't a CORS header, it just prevents the page being shown in (i)frames. What are you trying to achieve? Force google to be shown in an iframe?

Comment: I would like to make a GET request to this site and return the HTML

Comment: Read the file on your own server, or use a proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP only works if the URL you are calling contains data formatted as JSONP.

The URL you are using contains HTML not JSONP.

You cannot read arbitrary data with JSONP. It isn't a magic wand that disables the same-origin policy in browsers.

Comment: Thanks, so I guess what I want isn't possible.

Comment: Not with client-side code alone. You could read it with server-side code and proxy it that way.

Comment: I needed it to be client-side because I wanted cookies to work too.

Comment: Then that is impossible. It would be a horrible security problem if your website's JavaScript could read data from other websites using your visitors' credentials on those websites.